# View Controller with Windows phone tile effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am looking to add Windows phone tile effect to my Application's Dashboard ViewController, where user can resize the tile and reposition it and delete it, just a ViewController like the attached image. Is there any open source or samples available?

[image]

Comment: Have you googled it? There seems to be no clear problem stated in your question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that ordering by using a collection view with a custom UICollectionView layout.

More on customising layouts can be found in Apple Documentation [Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)